# Delete value from unordered-map with 3 elements

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Here is an MWE for the unordered map that I'm using. Based on what I understood [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/erase/), the public member function "erase" is used to erase the elements from the unordered map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int> > m;
    m.insert({3, std::make_pair(1,1)});
    m.insert({4, std::make_pair(5,1)});

    cout << m[4].first << endl;
    m.erase(4);
    cout << m[4].first << endl;
}
```

However, what I see from this example is as follows:

```
5
0
```

I was expecting only `5` and then throw an error that the key doesn't exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `m.at(4)` if you want an exception.

Comment: `m[4]` does default insert when key is not present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the [documentation](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), if a value does not exist in an `unordered_map`, `operator[]` will introduce a new element with the corresponding key. What you get back in the second query is the default-constructed pair, constructed by `operator[]`.

As @you pointed out in his comment, you can instead use [`at()`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) which includes a "range" check and throws an `std::out_of_range` exception if the key is now in the `unordered_map`.

If you want to avoid the exception, you can first check if [`m.find(4)==m.end()`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find), which indicates that the key 4 is not in the map, as pointed out by @YSC in his comment.

Comment: Might want to add a hint about `at()`.

Comment: You is right. Also a note about `find` to avoid forcing exception.

Comment: `try {
    m.at(4);
} catch (const out_of_range& e) {
    cout << "value doesn't exist" <<endl;
}
assert(m.find(4) != m.end());
`
Which of the two is "correct?

Comment: Depends on what you want to have. The first will print that the value doesn't exist while the other will crash due to a failed assert.